# git: ignore file unless it changes

Tags: git

I'm working with a git repo and I am including some automatically generated files. I don't want to commit those files unless I modify them by hand after generating them.

If I put them in a `.gitignore`, git will ignore them altogether, in their current state, and in future states.

If I don't, git will report them as unknown every time, which is unnecessary noise.

So, I'd like git to somehow remember their current state and never report those files as unknown/modified so long as they don't change, but without including them in the index for commit (or I might commit them by mistake).

I looked into `git update-index --assume-unchanged`, but that has the effect that git will ignore changes to the file unless I manually unset that flag. It would be easy to forget, and I want to delegate the responsibility of tracking the file onto git.

Comment: Alternative: only track patches (output of `diff`) to apply to generated files and have your build job apply those diffs if they exist.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for the general case of how to ignore a tracked file, which is [answered in the Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#ignore-tracked-files).  The answer is that this isn't possible:

> Git doesn’t provide a way to do this. The reason is that if Git needs to overwrite this file, such as during a checkout, it doesn’t know whether the changes to the file are precious and should be kept, or whether they are irrelevant and can safely be destroyed. Therefore, it has to take the safe route and always preserve them.
>
> It’s tempting to try to use certain features of git update-index, namely the assume-unchanged and skip-worktree bits, but these don’t work properly for this purpose and shouldn’t be used this way.

You shouldn't check generated files into the repository at all.  They bloat the repository and cause diff noise, and as you've found, it's impossible to determine when they should be updated and when they shouldn't.